# IE not resending cookies when printing

Tags: php, jquery, internet-explorer, cookies, printing

I have an image rendered on the fly by a PHP page request.php.  This image cannot be cached because of the nature of the data it contains. The image that's rendered by request.php depends on the user's cookies.  When I go to print from both IE8 and IE9, these cookies are not being sent in the request headers when attempting to download the image returned by request.php.  I determined this by using Fiddler and monitoring request/response headers.

My first idea was to just put the cookie information in the URL of request.php, but there's a problem with this. The cookies I set are created with the `httponly` flag set (for security reasons). In other words, I cannot access this cookie from a script. I do use jQuery to set the source for the image using something like `$("#myimage").attr("src", "request.php?d=" + dynamically_set_data_string);` There's no way to append any cookie information to this jQuery call because of the `httponly` flag.

I cannot use base64 to contain the image data directly in the `src` attribute because the images are too large (IE8 has a 32KB limit).

Is there a trick to force IE to send cookies in requests for uncached images made during printing/print preview?

Comment: Isn't the problem much more general - that IE simply doesn't re-request the entire resource when printing, and operates from the copy it stored in its cache? I don't think that can be circumvented...

Comment: I've specifically set headers to not cache the image that's returned (its contents can change at any time).  IE does re-request the image when printing, but it doesn't resend cookies in the re-request.

Comment: Guess if you can get around this, why not the user pressing the 'print screen' button on their keyboard. Scroll down a bit. Photshop it?

Comment: I think there's no other solution than to generate a one-time token, store it somewhere alongside the `SESSIONID` then append it to the image's `src` then retrieve it as `GET` parameter and finally invalidate it `unset`.

Comment: Guess if you can get around this, why not the user pressing the 'print screen' button on their keyboard. Scroll down a bit. Photshop it? So why circumvet tbhis behaviour?

Comment: Ed, I'm not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: @widrumstcs - You can just print a window - 'Print screen' button does this. You can scroll. Do another print screen. Put them together. Got the original. So why are you **TRYING** to preventing people to priting something that they have just looked at? Seems rather odd when they can do it anyway.

Comment: @Ed I'm not trying to prevent people from printing the image.  I want it to print.  It's just that IE doesn't resend the cookies when making the request to download the image during print preview/printing.

Comment: I wonder if using a cached version would help. When the page is viewed, cache the generated image and retrieve with an embedded query string param? Basically what @Adnan said I guess.

Comment: @wldrumstcs - What is the problem with them printing the image that is currently on their screen? Just change those `POST` to `GET` and ie will cache it.

Comment: @agrothe The issue with caching these images is that they are subject to change at any time.  Caching for even a short time is not desirable because of the nature of the data displayed in the image.

Comment: @wldrumstcs Can you embed the image as base64 encoded data instead? http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter/

Comment: @wldrumstcs, please re-read my comment. There won't be any cashing, there will be a one-time identifier to identify the user thus identifying the session without.

Comment: @agrothe Unfortunately I cannot.  The images I serve up are generally ~300KB.  We need to serve IE8 clients, and IE8 has a 32KB length limit when using base64.  Good suggestion, though.

Comment: @Adnan I think your solution might be the way to go.  I'm still hoping that there's a built-in solution for IE that doesn't require the development required by your solutoin.

Comment: @wldrumstcs - You can ask those images to be caches for say 10 minutes. If you need less perhaps web technology is the wrong way to go. (I would even go to say why cannot a person get the same image again irrespective of the time). Just enable it (the image) to be cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing research, it looks like there's no way for IE to send cookie data in the request headers for uncached images when printing.  To get around this, I use the `window.onbeforeprint` event to add a `cache=true` parameter to my image's URL.  On the backend, I set headers for the image to be cached for a short time period.  Although this doesn't fix the problem (because I don't believe there is a true fix), it does circumvent the issue, and IE is able to print the image.